# Contar los elementos de un array que cumplan una condición

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de obtener el numero de veces en los que un elemento de un arreglo cumpla una condición.

La situación es la siguiente: necesito saber cuantos elementos de mi arreglo cumplen una condición.

Tengo mi arreglo de esta forma:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 97
    [2] => 9
    [3] => sin
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 97
    [2] => 9
    [3] => sin
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 97
    [2] => 9
    [3] => con
)
```

Aquí necesito saber lo siguiente: cuantos elementos tienen el valor **sin** y cuantos elementos tiene el valor **con**.

Esto lo necesito para ejecutar lo siguiente: cuando existan 6 o mas elementos con el valor "sin" debo hacer un descuento. Si hay 12 o mas debo hacer otro tipo de descuento.

La verdad no consigo como contar los elementos que me cumplan esa condición. No he intentado mucho ya que no se me ocurre nada bueno hasta ahora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una otra forma de hacerlo sería con [iteradores recursivos](http://php.net/manual/es/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php), suponiendo que lo que tienes es un array asociativo.

```
/*Datos de ejemplo*/
$arr=array(
               array(1,97,9,"sin"),
               array(1,97,9,"con"),
               array(1,97,9,"sin"),
               array(1,97,8,"con"),
               array(1,97,9,"sin")

           );    

$mIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));
$totalSin=0;
$totalCon=0;

foreach ($mIterator as $v) {
    $totalSin = ($v==='sin') ? ++$totalSin : $totalSin+0;  
    $totalCon = ($v==='con') ? ++$totalCon : $totalCon+0;  
}
var_dump($totalSin); 
var_dump($totalCon);
```

**Salida:**

```
int(3)
int(2)
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta Cedano, sin duda debe ser la forma mas optima para hacer lo que requiero. Mano arriba! Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Primero el array que tienes parece el resultado de una impresion de array, creeria que tu array original es:

```
$var1=array(1, 97, 9, 'sin');
$var2=array(1,97,9,'con');
```

para saber que elemento esta el el array hay que recorrerlo:

```
for ($i=0; $i <count($var1) ; $i++) {
  if ($var1[$i]=="sin") {
    $contadorSin=$contadorSin+1;
}elseif ($var1[$i]=="con") {
   $contadorCon=$contadorCon+1;
   }
}
for ($i=0; $i <count($var2) ; $i++) {
   if ($var2[$i]=="sin") {
      $contadorSin=$contadorSin+1;
}elseif ($var2[$i]=="con") {
   $contadorCon=$contadorCon+1;
 }
}
echo("Con:".$contadorCon);
echo("Sin:".$contadorSin);
```